# Why does this method override inside a method fail?

Tags: java, overriding

I'm a java newbie and currently going through a training material with questions and answers. The below code gets compile error saying

```
The method Hello() is undefined for the type Hello
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, as the code makes sense to me. Kindly provide some explanation. Thanks!

```
public class Hello {
    String title;
    int value;

    public Hello() {
        title += "World";
    }

    public Hello(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        title = "Hello";
        Hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods that use the class name are constructors, and if you are going to call a constructor from another constructor, then it has to be as the first line of the constructor and you would call it via `this()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have 2 constructors in your class and no methods. If you want methods, name them differently than the class name and use `camelCase`. Also, don't forget to write the return type. If you don't want to return anything, use `void`. For example, this compiles:

```
public class Hello {   

    String title;
    int value;

    public void append() {
        title += "World";
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        title = "Hello";
        append();
    }
}
```

If you want to have constructors, not methods, you must call other constructor with `this()` and it must be in the first line:

```
public class Hello {   

    String title;
    int value;

    public Hello() {
        title += "World";
    }

    public Hello(int value) {
        this();
        this.value = value;
        title = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...  Howver, If I call this() in the first line of Hello(int value), it will only make the title as 'World', and two lines later, it will be again changed to 'Hello', is that right?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot call the constructor in the later calls of your other overloaded constructor.
the call to constructor of the same class or super class has to be the first statement in the constructor.
and you have to call it by this() or super()

```
public Hello(int value){
    this();
    this.value=value;
    title = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: So, 'this()' would refer to any of the other constructors I define for the class. For example, if I wish to call Hello(int value) in Hello(), I should add this(int value) to the first line in Hello()?

Comment: Exactly. this() has to take the form of the overloaded constructor you are calling. the arguments should MATCH to that of desired constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says, you haven't implemented a method named `Hello`. You have implemented a *constructor for the Hello class*, but not a method `Hello()`. If you want to call another constructor, it has to be `this(...)` or `super(...)`, and the very first line of the constructor.

It appears to be linguistically accepted to declare a method `Hello()`, which you would do by adding a return type, like so:

```
public type Hello() {
    ...
}
```

but I would strongly discourage it.